# Multiple visual studio projects/solutions on the go

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, vb.net

I am working on a large asp.net app as a single developer.  I will often work on a number of change requests concurrently.  For example, a change required to the Finance component and a change required to the sales component.

I sometimes create a separate project to hold the changes and then reference the main application (file reference to the assembly).  Is this a common approach or are there any tool/techniques that make this easier?

For example, I make a change to the sales component, I will create a new project (SalesChange.sln) and if I make a change to the Finance component then I will create a new project called FinanceChange.sln.  FinanceChange.sln and SalesChange.sln reference MainProject.sln and will eventually be migrated to MainProject.sln.

Comment: Sounds like a lot of work.  I hope you're using source control of some sort.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like what you want is to be able to do is demo changes without having to make them to the "original" project. Most people use source control with branching to accomplish this.

Comment: +1 for branching. I will do some reading on this to confirm your thoughts. I will then come back and mark the answer.